# Argument of type '<U>(data: U) => unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MutationKey'

Tags: javascript, react-query

I'm using Next.js 14, TypeScript and react-query in my project.

I have this API client file:

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-return */
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment */
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access */
import axios from 'axios';
import { BASE_URL } from '../constants/url-resources';
import { deleteCookie, getCookie } from 'cookies-next';
import { COOKIE_KEY } from '../constants/keys';



// if(import.meta.env.VITE_MP_API_URL){
//     // apiUrl = import.meta.env.VITE_MP_API_URL;
// }

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: BASE_URL
});

class APIClient<T> {
    endpoint: string;

    constructor(endpoint: string) {
        this.endpoint = endpoint;
        axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
            const token = getCookie(COOKIE_KEY);
            config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
            config.withCredentials = true
            return config;
        });

        axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
            (response) => {
                return response;
            },
            (error) => {
                const {response} = error;
                if (response.status === 401) {
                    deleteCookie(COOKIE_KEY);
                    // window.location.reload();
                } else if (response.status === 404) {
                    // Show not found
                }

                throw error;
            }
        );
    }

    get = (id: number) => {
        return axiosInstance
            .get<T>(`${this.endpoint}/${id}`)
            .then(
                // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
                // @ts-ignore
                (res) => res.data.data
            );
    }

    getAll = () => {
        return axiosInstance
            .get<T[]>(this.endpoint)
            .then(
                // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
                // @ts-ignore
                (res) => res.data.data
            );
    }

    put = <U>(id: number, data: U) => {
        return axiosInstance
            .put<T>(`${this.endpoint}/${id}`, data)
            .then(
                // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
                // @ts-ignore
                (res) => res.data.data);
    }

    post = <U>(data: U) => {
        try {
            return axiosInstance
            .post<T>(this.endpoint, data)
            .then(res => res.data);
        }
        catch(err) {
            return err;
        }
    }

    delete = (id: number) => {
        return axiosInstance
            .delete(`${this.endpoint}/${id}`)
            .then(res => res.data);
    }
}

export default APIClient;
```

This login hook:

```
export const useLogin = () => useMutation<ILoginResponse, AxiosError<any>, ILoginInput>(loginService.post);
```

and this function in my login form:

```
  const handleLogin = async (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();

      const credentials: ILoginInput = { email: email, password: password };
      const res = await loginMutation.mutateAsync(credentials);
      console.log("res", res);
  
      if(res){
        setDataAfterLogin(res);
      }
  };
```

The problem is that I get this message in the login hook:

```
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type '<U>(data: U) => unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MutationKey'.ts(2769)
useMutation.d.ts(6, 25): The last overload is declared here.
```

And it happens only when I'm using post method and I have try-catch structure there.

Could you give me some ideas why this happens and possible solution about it?

1. I've read about the MutationKey type and tried changing them in the hook, but nothing changes
2. Configuring try-catch in another way, but it doesn't help

Comment: You probably should not return `err` in `post()`.

Comment: @rveerd nope, I still get this message: not assignable to parameter of type 'MutationKey'